# Can someone help me on consuming text file in rest-api?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have below code which consumes input using `@RequestBody`. But I'm trying to write a `@PostMapping` request which consumes a text file. But I'm not aware on how to achieve my desired requirement. Can someone please help me on achieving the desired result?

```
@PostMapping(value = "/getInput")
public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> getInput(@RequestBody InputData inputData) {
    // rest of the code..
}
```

Comment: Do you want to upload a file? Then you should check out this article. See https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-file-upload-example/

Comment: Thanks but, I'm not looking for uploading a file. I want to consume the .txt file coming from client and to read the file content.

Comment: What is inputData here?

Comment: Just a pojo class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something as below:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/getInput")
public ResponseEntity<String> uploadFile(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {
    try {
        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
        Path path = Paths.get(file.getOriginalFilename());
        Files.write(path, bytes);
        System.out.println(path.getFileName());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Good Job", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But is there is any way to extract the content from the file. The content will be in a json format. So basically A Json format data is stored in the file and we need to extract that json format data.

Comment: What you can do is read the multipart file as string(which will be our json string) and then convert that to specific object. I don't think there is any direct method as file could have any type of data. Try this:
           String content = new String ( Files.readAllBytes( Paths.get(filePath) ) );
          InputData data = new ObjectMapper().readValue(content, InputData.class);
 Catch necessary exceptions.